# Nested vectors do not follow promotion rules. Solution has a bug.

Tags: c++, vector, nested, type-promotion

This program adds nested vectors, but does not promote the types correctly. I think std::plus needs to take in T1 or T2 depending on basic type promotion rules.  The original problem is in this post ([decltype does not resolve nested vectors. How can I use templates for nested vectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30873671/decltype-does-not-resolve-nested-vectors-how-can-i-use-templates-for-nested-vec/30874396#30874396)).

main.cpp

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T1>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, std::vector<T1> r){
    if(r.size() == 0){
        return stream;
    }
    else{
        stream << "(";
        for(int i = 0; i < r.size(); i++){
            if(i < (r.size() - 1)){
                stream << r[i] << ", ";
            }
            else{
                stream << r[i] << ")";
            }
        }
    }
    return stream;
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct Add : std::plus<T1> { };//<-Here T1 or T2 depending on their types.

template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct Add<std::vector<T1>, std::vector<T2>>
{   
    auto operator()(const std::vector<T1>& l, const std::vector<T2>& r)
        -> std::vector<decltype(Add<T1,T2>{}(l[0], r[0]))>
    {
        using type = decltype(Add<T1,T2>{}(l[0], r[0]));
        std::vector<type> ans;

        if(l.size() == std::max(l.size(),r.size()))
            std::transform(r.begin(), r.end(), l.begin(), std::back_inserter(ans), Add<T1,T2>{});
        else
            std::transform(l.begin(), l.end(), r.begin(), std::back_inserter(ans), Add<T1,T2>{});
        return ans;
    };
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto operator+(const std::vector<T1>& lhs, const std::vector<T2>& rhs)
    -> decltype(Add<std::vector<T1>, std::vector<T2>>{}(lhs, rhs))
{
    return Add<std::vector<T1>, std::vector<T2>>{}(lhs, rhs);
}

int main(){
    std::vector<int> e = {1};
    std::vector<double> q = {1.5};

    //Incorrect result = 2
    std::cout << (e + q) << std::endl;
    //Correct result = 2.5
    std::cout << (q + e) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in your code (that I got wrong in my answer to your original question). The first, as mentioned by [vsoftco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30879351/2069064) is using [`std::common_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) for the base case.

The second is a simple error. Consider this if statement:

```
    if(l.size() == std::max(l.size(),r.size()))
        std::transform(r.begin(), r.end(), l.begin(), std::back_inserter(ans), 
                       Add<T1,T2>{});
    else
        std::transform(l.begin(), l.end(), r.begin(), std::back_inserter(ans), 
                       Add<T1,T2>{});
```

`Add<T1,T2>::operator()`, in the partial specialization case, takes two arguments: a `std::vector<T1>` and a `std::vector<T2>`, **in that order**. But in the two branches of the `if` statement, we're actually calling them in different orders. In the `true` branch, we're calling them in the REVERSE order, so just have to invert the ordering in the template:

```
    if(l.size() == std::max(l.size(),r.size()))
        std::transform(r.begin(), r.end(), l.begin(), std::back_inserter(ans), 
                       Add<T2,T1>{});
```

Should actually just remove the `if`-statement altogether so that the specialization case is now:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2> 
struct Add<std::vector<T1>, std::vector<T2>>
{   
    using R = decltype(Add<T1,T2>{}(std::declval<T1>(), std::declval<T2>()));

    std::vector<R> operator()(const std::vector<T1>& l, const std::vector<T2>& r)
    {
        std::vector<R> ans;

        std::transform(l.begin(),
                       l.begin() + std::min(l.size(), r.size()),
                       r.begin(),
                       std::back_inserter(ans),
                       Add<T1,T2>{});
        return ans;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`std::common_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) when defining the primary template `Add<>`, like this (must `#include <type_traits>`):

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct Add : std::plus<typename std::common_type<T1,T2>::type> { };//<-Here T1 or T2 depending on their types.
```

You basically tell the `Add` primary template to use the "best" type. Then the specialization will use the primary, and the latter now takes care of the promotion.

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84ef10225984f833)

Comment: @dylan Because `type` it is a dependent type (depends on the template parameters `T1` and `T2`), [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) for more details.

Comment: Unfortunately, now when I try adding nested vectors of different types I get an compiler error.

Comment: So, something like this will not work:       ` `std::vector<std::vector<int>> e = {{1},{1}};
 std::vector<std::vector<double>> q = {{1.5},{1.5}};

 std::cout << (e + q) << std::endl;`

Comment: But I was able to add them before when they were only one dimensional vectors. Now I cant add different type nested vectors.

Comment: This works just fine: `std::vector<int> e = {1};
    std::vector<double> q = {1.5};

    std::cout << (e + q) << std::endl;`